# Compare Two strings in O(logn) with some pre-processing and assumption

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I am thinking if it possible to compare two string in O(log n) with some pre-processing and assumption.

My pre-processing is to store the string as the AVL tree where the value of the node is the Ascii value of the character. Since I am using the same algorithm to build the AVL tree, two idental string will have the same AVL tree. 
As a result, we may not need to check all nodes. Is it possible to only check O(log n) nodes to know if two trees are the same? If not, will it be possible to build another tree structure that achieve my goal?

Comment: What are the bounds about the assumption? And if you have only one test case why does it called pre-processing?

Comment: Btw I think the answer is no. You can take an full AVL tree, lowest level of the tree has `n / 2` leaves, than let's take the same tree but the smallest element is now 1 smaller. Or any element in the lowest level of the tree is 1 smaller but the order in the sorted array is not changed. Since there are `O(n)` elements you can change like that but the structure remains the same you can not compare them in `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building an AVL tree where the value of the node is the ASCII value of the character, then wouldn't "STOP" and "SPOT" result in the same AVL tree? What if the strings were "aaaaaaaa" and "aaaaaaab"? Those strings are 8 characters long. Which three characters will you compare? Would that work for "aaaabaaa", as well?

The answer is no. Your idea won't work.